# Find all items in dataset variable with comma-separated strings

Tags: r

I'm trying to get all of the unique items in a data frame variable with comma separated strings:

I have this dataframe
`df = data.frame(v1 = c("A,S", "A,B,F", "A,B,C,D"))`

And I want the outcome to be this:

A,B,C,D,F,S

A loop would work but I know there's an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can split the column by `,`, get the `sort`ed `unique` elements from `unlist`ing the `list`

```
sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(df$v1, ","))))
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "F" "S"
```

---

Or using `tidyverse` - split the column 'v1' at the delimiter, return the `distinct` rows and `arrange` the rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   separate_rows(v1) %>% 
   distinct(v1) %>% 
   arrange(v1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  v1   
  <chr>
1 A    
2 B    
3 C    
4 D    
5 F    
6 S
```